# Python - Convert String into Iterable Integer List

Tags: python, string, list, integer, literate-programming

I am developing a Twitch Python IRC Bot that has a currency system. The balances of users are stored in a list, which is loaded from and saved to a text file. However, because the text file's content is loading into one singular string that is then placed inside the list, I cannot iterate through each entry in the string to add points to it. For example, here is the iterable list I'm looking for: `[10, 21, 42, 5]`

But, when this is saved to a text file and then loaded into the list, it turns out like this: `['10, 21, 42, 5', '0'` (with a 0 entry added on). As you can see, this would iterate through the list with only recognizing 2 sections, which is where the quotations surround. Is there a way I can convert the string fetched from the text file into a list of **integers** that I can iterate through? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you saving to the text file, and how are you loading it?

Comment: Consider something like a dict that gets serialized with `json` instead.  The `dict` keys can be user identifiers and the values can be the balances.

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if your post code (in a minimal fashion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## DISCLAIMER:

All the other answers are *very* good suggestions on good practices for storing data and reading them in later, but since you specifically asked how to *"convert the string fetched from the text file into a list of integers ..."*, I will gladly help to do exactly such thing.

However, while this answer may be suitable for the exact thing you requested to be done, it is by no means the *best practice* to achieve what you want (saving in lists of integers, which would be better off done with JSON or YAML).

---

## SOLUTION

Okay, this seems fairly simple.

You have an original list `[10, 21, 42, 5]`.

You save it to a text file, then read it as a list only to find there are two sections (and they're giving back strings + what is that extra `0`?!):

`['10, 21, 42, 5', '0']`

Seems like you only need the first section, so:

```
>>> x = ['10, 21, 42, 5', '0']
>>> y = x[0]
>>> print(y)
'10, 21, 42, 5'
>>> print(type(y))
str
```

But wait, that returns a string! Easy, just split by the separator `", "`:

```
>>> z = y.split(", ")
>>> print(z)
['10', '21', '42', '5']
```

Now it returns a list, but it's still a list of strings, so all we got to do is convert every element of the list into type `int` (integer). This is easy enough to do with a standard `for` loop, but we can make this a one-liner with the `map` function:

```
...
>>> print(z)
['10', '21', '42', '5']
>>> z = map(int, z)  # apply int() to every elem; equi. to [int('10'), int('21'), int('42'), int('5')]
>>> print(z)
[10, 21, 42, 5]
>>> print(map(type, z))  # print out type of every element in list
[int, int, int, int]
```

---

## CONCLUSION

So, given the read-in list of bizarre strings `x = ['10, 42, 21, 5', '0']`, you can get your desired list of integers with:

```
z = map(int, x[0].split(", "))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you save *to* the file, you'll want to do so cleanly-- make sure that you write in a consistent format.

When you read from the file, I suggest using `literal_eval` from the `ast` package. This will turn any strings contained in the file into Python types.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried writing the list to a yaml file instead of a text file?

```
import yaml

myfile = path/to/my/file
mylist = [10, 21, 42, 5]

with open(myfile,'w') as handle:
    yaml.dump(mylist, handle, default_flow_style=False)

with open(myfile,'r') as handle:
    retrieved_list = yaml.load(handle)

print retrieved_list
```